# having confusion with ob_start()

Tags: php

so i have a file, that loads content from another file. both these files require a file that connects to db, the connection file at the top has ob_start(), and under that, session_start(), fine. When i view the parent file (that loads content (using JS) from another file) i get:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/xxxx/public_html/child_file.page.php:1) in /home/xxxx/public_html/connection.inc.php on line 3

so then in the child file i put ob_start() at the top, but there was still the error?

Comment: Do you have any output before your opening PHP tags? `ob_start()` can't help you if it's called after output is sent. Could we possibly see the file?

Comment: i will show you the relavant bits of the files, sure... give me a sec

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZNdQzjyc --there you go!

Comment: What do you mean by "javascript loading the child". The child is not referenced using `include` or `require`? Also, unfortunately this doesn't really show whether or not you have spaces before your opening PHP tags.

Comment: correct, i am using js for a number of irrelevant reasons!

Comment: Can you show the piece of code that's including the child file, or otherwise getting content from it?

Comment: sure..http://pastebin.com/XYuw8TV6

Comment: That doesn't look like `child_file.page.php`. Is `child_file.page.php` being included by that, or did you just rename it in the error you posted above? If you know for a fact that there's no output coming before your `ob_start()`, my only suggestion is to open the file with an editor such as `vi` and look for strange characters known us a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark at the beginning. The error is telling you exactly where to look: `child_file.page.php` on line 1.

Comment: SORRy! i meant http://pastebin.com/KThmPYmw

Answer (score 0):

if **session_start()** is before the all code and **include** or **require** :

1) check for space and newline before **< ?php**

2) check for page  Unicode  like: **UTF-8**  your page must be like ISO-8859-1

Comment: Your page does not have to be ISO-8859-1. It can very easily be UTF-8. As long as there's no Byte Order Mark

Comment: no, i do not use Include or require to get load the child file to the parent file....

Comment: @CasparWylie No any  space and newline html code ,... before < ?php ?

Comment: do one test.make a new page with ANSI Unicode without any  space and newline html code ,...  start **< ?php** then put **header('Location:http ://google.com');** on it then close php and test it. keep Me informed.

Comment: right...how do i do with ANSI Unicode? and what should i tell you when i finished?

Comment: in your editor like **notepad++** set Encoding as ANSI . send me result. error Accord or not?

Comment: better to use notepad then upload file on server.

Comment: is ther another way of doing this ?

Answer (score -2):

`session_start();`
 Needs to be infront of anything else that might output something to the screen. So for example in this case, you would put:

```
session_start();
ob_start();
```

Comment: Even though he's using `ob_start` both in the parent and the child?

Comment: you been before anything? even ob_start()?

Comment: i am not using ob_start() in the parent file, only the child file because that is what the error is talking about...

Comment: The problem is that you are outputting something before session_start();, if you do that the session cannot start, just put session_start(); right after <?php and before any other data and it should be fine.

Comment: ok, so i tried that in the connection page (the file that has both session_start and ob_start) and put session_start before ob_start, but  no difference..

Comment: are you including the file with session_start(); in anything else? if so, you need to put session_start(); into the parent file, any output before it will result in a failure to start the session, which is exactly what is happening here.